# R CMD build: file DESCRIPTION does not exist

Tags: r, cran

After editing the DESCRIPTION file in a package I am developing, I am not able to use R CMD build anymore. R seems to be unable to read it.

Here is the error message:

```
$ R CMD build ~/projects/mypackage

* checking for file ‘/home/user/projects/mypackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘mypackage’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* running ‘cleanup’
Error in .read_description(ldpath) : 
  file 'mypackage/DESCRIPTION' does not exist
Execution halted
```

It *is* rather cryptic, isn't it ?

The file is here of course, and it is even found by R in the first line.
As you might expect, removing the DESCRIPTION file make the process fail on the first check:

```
$ R CMD build ~/projects/mypackage

* checking for file ‘/home/user/projects/mypackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... NO
```

**Observations**:

- I tried to run it from another relative path (`mypackage`, `.`) without success.
- It also failed on the CI server, and on a freshly cloned repository.
- `R CMD check ~/projects/mypackage` runs without error as well as `R -e "library(devtools); load_all();"` (only a couple of unrelated warnings)
- The only resource I have found is [a similar bug affecting windows builds](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~nunes/computerstuff/Rhelp/Rpackages-orig.html). I am not in this situation.
- If I change the content of the `Package` field in DESCRIPTION to `foo`, without changing anything else, the error becomes `Error in .read_description(ldpath) : file 'mypackage/DESCRIPTION' does not exist`
- There is a cleanup script deleting a bunch of files. Removing it does not solve the problem.

I am running:

- R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) (Debian Jessie)

Comment: What's the error message you get when the `DESCRIPTION` file is found?  Sometimes error messages can be misleading: I discovered one of my man pages (function.rd) failed because what I thought was an ASCI ' " '  turned out to be an unacceptable unicode quotation mark.

Comment: It is `Error in .read_description(ldpath) : 
  file 'mypackage/DESCRIPTION' does not exist
Execution halted` as stated in the question.

Comment: Do you have a cleanup script or otherwise cause R to change working directory?

Comment: It might be something like that. I tried to change to file to one generated by `create(foo)` and I get `Error in .read_description(ldpath) : 
  file 'foo/DESCRIPTION' does not exist
Execution halted
`. Even if the folder name did not change (only the Package field in DESCRIPTION). It means that it is looking for the file... based on its very content ??

Comment: Removing the cleanup script does not change a thing. Is there something else that might be executed before this point ?

Comment: Could you try running clean and rebuild? It could be something dumb like not having x.x.x as a version number or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this .Rbuildignore would trigger error

```
^sccomp\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^\.github
^README*
^dev*
```

This would not

```
^sccomp\.Rproj$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^\.github
^README*
^dev
```

The difference is the asterisk after ^dev

If I can comment, this is shocking and made me waste 2 days. I'm wondering how can I notify R people

Comment: As unexpected as it sounds, I can confirm this. Changing in .Rbuildignore the line from `^_*` to `^_` or `^_*$` removed the error message `DESCRIPTION' does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Comments the setwd line in my .Rprofile, and all errors gone, really saved my ass:

`#setwd("~/.R/work")`

I've been tortured a few days by this error:

```
Error in tools:::.read_description(file) :
  file 'DESCRIPTION' does not exist
```

You can check out https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/set-up.html

> a seemingly innocent call to setwd() in .Rprofile, for example, will break devtools build and check functions.